# How to update nickname on_member_update discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a bot that prevents nickname changes, but cannot figure out how to make a nickname update inside an on_member_update.

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(memberBefore,memberAfter):
        if memberBefore.nick != memberAfter.nick:
```

I cannot figure out what to put within the if statement.
Using discord.py 1.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Like anywhere else, simply `Member.edit` and pass the `nick` kwarg

```py
await memberAfter.edit(nick="whatever")
```

#### Reference:

- [`Member.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit)